# Discord button stop working if the bot is inactive

Tags: python, button, discord, discord.py, bots

i have a discord bot which is working properly. But if i leave the bot alone for at least 5 min the button what was posted below a message, stop working even if the bot is online.
I run the script from my computer but i tried online services.
What could cause this error?

i tried online services, my computer.
but after 5 min the button stop working.

Heres my code: pastebin.com/zShRaYig

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The timeout is 180 seconds which is 3 minutes... Just increase it or disable it

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński i tried it with emoji react, its works after a hour tho. where or how should i increase that?

Comment: [How to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please include a minimal working example _in_ the body of your question and not linking to it externally.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the [`timeout`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.View.timeout) when you create your `View` class. So assuming that you have your own view that's subclassed from `discord.ui.View` then:

```py
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    # rest of your view class
```

*Or*, alternatively, you can override the [`on_timeout`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.View.on_timeout) function and edit the message accordingly when it does timeout.

```py
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    async def on_timeout(self):
        await self.message.edit(content="This has timed out. Please create another.", view=None)
    
    # rest of your view class
```